# Can you use MySQL to connect to a standalone database e.g. "mydata.db"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Pretty sure the answer is "no" but I have found no conclusive result...

Basically, can use MySQL to connect to a standalone database file and then use standard MySQL commands on it? Currently I use SQLite3 to do exactly this but I now like the usage of MySQL commands whilst retaining the single file devoid of a MySQL server. Is it possible?

Ilmiont

Comment: To my knowledge MySQL databases physically correspond to a folder of files, not a single file. In my installation I see these folders under <MySQLDir>\data\... I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but it may be possible to configure MySQL to look for databases elsewhere. I'd advise against copying databases from one computer to another, especially if you have different versions of MySQL. Apart from asking us if this is possible... why don't you tell use **why** you'd like to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with mysql function, but still possible with `PDO`. Most SQL Commands should work in any SQL Based RDBMS.

PDO is meant to have a generic interface, so even if you would have a MySQL Database, you should consider developing in `PDO`.

Here is a Example for SQLLite3:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/

If you want to get deeper into `PDO`, read this article:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Thanks, that clarified it. I will accept your answer when it lets me.