# Can I create an individual database file like .mdb in ms-access using MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I am confused on how to use the database I have created inside MySQL. Can I create a database file from it and put it in a folder and access it via a vb.net project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190599/vb-net-mysql-connection

Comment: It sounds like you want a [standalone database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1016063/1115360). Otherwise: [Can you use MySQL to connect to a standalone database e.g. “mydata.db”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610086/can-you-use-mysql-to-connect-to-a-standalone-database-e-g-mydata-db)

Comment: The location of the database is not important. It could be on the local machine or off on the internet somewhere. You connect to a database hosted by MySql server not a file. You use the methods and objects available in ADO.net to do this.

Comment: If you don't want to have to connect to a server then don't use a server-based database. If you want to use just a file then use a file-based database, e.g. SQLite. If you use a server-based database then you need to have a server available, either on the same machine or elsewhere, and connect to it.